# find a duplicate count of 4 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried two methods of trying to find a duplicate count of 4 in the player column in sql. They both produce the same results.  I specifically want duplicates of the player column. When I look through my column tab of player none of them have a single duplicate. What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

```
SELECT tournament,player,prize_money,position FROM earnings where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3;
+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
| tournament | player | prize_money | position |
+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|        797 |      1 |       50000 |        1 |
|       4969 |      2 |         100 |        1 |
|         79 |      3 |       45231 |        1 |
|         74 |      4 |         921 |        1 |
|        799 |      5 |        5000 |        1 |
|       1801 |      6 |       10663 |        1 |
|       3082 |      8 |         652 |        1 |
|       2157 |     10 |       30000 |        1 |
|       1366 |     11 |       30000 |        1 |
|        322 |     12 |        1375 |        1 |
|        167 |     13 |       42690 |        1 |


SELECT * FROM earnings where position = 1 group by player having count(*) > 3;
+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
| tournament | player | prize_money | position |
+------------+--------+-------------+----------+
|        797 |      1 |       50000 |        1 |
|       4969 |      2 |         100 |        1 |
|         79 |      3 |       45231 |        1 |
|         74 |      4 |         921 |        1 |
|        799 |      5 |        5000 |        1 |
|       1801 |      6 |       10663 |        1 |
|       3082 |      8 |         652 |        1 |
|       2157 |     10 |       30000 |        1 |
|       1366 |     11 |       30000 |        1 |
|        322 |     12 |        1375 |        1 |
|        167 |     13 |       42690 |        1 |
```

Here is the big join I have.

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.tag, players.game_race,
       earnings.tournament, earnings.player, earnings.position,
       tournaments.tournament_id, tournaments.region
  FROM players
  JOIN earnings ON players.player_id = earnings.player 
  JOIN tournaments ON earnings.tournament = tournaments.tournament_id
  where position = 1
ORDER BY players.player_id;
```

I would like to combine it with Md. Suman Kabir answer below that was done for me.

```
SELECT tournament, earnings.player, prize_money, position 
FROM earnings 
    join (
        SELECT player FROM earnings 
        where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3) 
    as DupPlayer
on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
where position = 1
```

Comment: `count(*)` counts all rows, while `count(col)` counts non-null rows. I see no null's in the table, so they will return the same value.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done. How big of a difference is each database type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bedd6c/7)

Use this :

**Note:** This will work if you want to get duplicate records based on the column `player` only.

```
SELECT tournament, earnings.player, prize_money, position 
FROM earnings 
    join (
        SELECT player FROM earnings 
        where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3) 
    as DupPlayer
on earnings.player=DupPlayer.player
where position = 1
```

**If** you want to get the duplicate records based on all the four columns, you can use this query :

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bedd6c/5)

```
SELECT tournament, player, prize_money, position 
FROM earnings 
where position = 1 
group by tournament, player, prize_money, position 
having count(player) > 3;
```

Comment: What about this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bedd6c/1  Why is it ignoring (897, 1, 50000, 1)? I specifically want duplicates of the player column.

Comment: Check the first answer, it will not ignore (897, 1, 50000, 1)

Comment: Why is the position ignoring the `position = 1`? http://pasted.co/2149177b

Comment: Use `where position = 1` at the end of the query, see [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bedd6c/7)

Comment: is there a way to combine with a big join query that I have? Should I open a new question for this? I am adding the big join I have above.

Comment: Better to post a new question rather to extend the question based on answer of previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:

```
SELECT tournament,player,prize_money,position 
FROM earnings 
where position = 1 AND player in(
    SELECT player
    FROM earnings 
    where position = 1 group by player having count(player) > 3
    )
```

Comment: This works except it is ignoring the `group by player` part. It sorts by the tournament colomn. Is there a way to fix that?